# Thread safe counter using python's multiprocessing starmap

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, multiprocessing, shared-memory

At the moment I'm trying to handle results from a calculation which come in very fast. At first I inserted each simulation result into an sqlite database but it turned out to be the bottleneck of the entire calculation. So I ended up using cursor.executemany instead of cursor.execute which is much faster.

My problem is now that I'm somehow not able to implement a thread safe counter.

The executemany task should be run every 1000 calculations. Therefore I implemented an initializer with a multiprocessing.Value I also tried this solution (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing) but somehow some values of the counter are duplicates which ends up in running the executemany task to often or not at all.

If anybody has an idea how to solve this issue I'd really appreciate it.

Here's a minimum sample:

```
import multiprocessing, sqlite3
from multiprocessing import Value, Lock
from itertools import repeat

def worker(Testvalues, TotalValues):
    MP_counter.value += 1
    counter.increment()

    con = sqlite3.connect("Test.db", timeout=30.0)
    cur = con.cursor()
    # Minimum sample:
    Helper = list(range(5))
    Helper = [x * Testvalues for x in Helper]
    GList.append(Helper)

    Execute_Every = 10
    print("Counter class: %d" % (counter.value()))
    print("MP_counter: %d" % (MP_counter.value))

    if counter.value() % Execute_Every == 0 or counter.value() == TotalValues - 1:
        print("Execute query")
        print("Counter class: %d" % (counter.value()))
        print("MP_counter: %d" % (MP_counter.value))

        Helper = [tuple(row) for row in GList[:Execute_Every]]
        del GList[:Execute_Every]
        cur.executemany(
            "INSERT INTO Test (One, Two, Three, Four, Five) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", Helper)
        con.commit()

    con.close()

def setup(t, g, c):
    global MP_counter
    global GList
    global counter
    MP_counter = t
    GList = g
    counter = c

class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        self.val = Value('i', initval)
        self.lock = Lock()

    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val.value += 1

    def value(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.val.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    CPUS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    MP_counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    GList = m.list([])
    thread_safe_counter = Counter(0)

    l = multiprocessing.Lock()
    WORKERS = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=setup, initargs=[MP_counter, GList, thread_safe_counter],processes=CPUS)

    con = sqlite3.connect("Test.db", timeout=30.0)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')
    SQLCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (One INT, Two INT, Three INT, Four INT, Five INT);"
    cur.execute(SQLCommand)
    con.close()

    TotalValues = 100
    Testvalues = list(range(TotalValues))

    WORKERS.starmap(worker, zip(Testvalues, repeat(TotalValues)))
    WORKERS.close()
    WORKERS.join()
    #Check if list is empty
    print(GList)
```

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter has an `increment()` and a `value()` method, which need to be called separately, so to make this safe you'd have to call both operations while holding the lock. Your `increment()` method should return the new value after incrementing it, and you should use that without further calls to `value()`, e.g:

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        self.val = Value('i', initval)
        self.lock = Lock()

    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val.value += 1
            return self.val.value

...

def worker(Testvalues, TotalValues):
    counter_value = counter.increment()
    # use only counter_value from here on
    ...
```

Also, a [`Value`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) is already created with a default `RLock`, which can be overridden in the constructor call with a different lock type if needed. So you don't really need to allocate your own lock, you could just use:

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        self.val = Value('i', initval)
        # or Value('i', initval, lock=Lock())

    def increment(self):
        with self.val.get_lock():
            self.val.value += 1
            return self.val.value
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work at least for the counter but somehow not every value is inserted into the database. If I run it, sometimes there are 100, 96 or 98 values in the database. Do you know why that is?

Comment: From what I can say you also have race conditions with the way you use your managed list (`GList`), operations on that list should also be synchronized by a lock, otherwise it's not guaranteed that all workers have already added their items to the list when you access it and you end up deleting elements not added to the db, or there may be left over items at the end.